# Is there a better way to handle multiple IF statements in C#

Tags: c#

Can anyone tell me how can I write in a better way the below code?
I have to sequentially execute all these methods. It will proceed further if previous methods succeed.

```
var result =  CreateCustomerRequest(requestDataInput);
                if (result.Error.HasError == false)
                {
                    var result1 = GetCustomerInfo(new FetchCustomerDataInput());
                    if (result1.Error.HasError == false)
                    {
                        var result2 = SaveCustomerDetails(result1.cutomer);
                        if (result2.Error.HasError == false)
                        {
                            var result3 = CreateCustomerItemMappingRequest(result2.IdList);
                            if (result3.Error.HasError == false)
                            {
                                var result4 = UpdateCustomerRequestStatus(RequestId);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: The common argument against indicating errors in return values is that callers can forget to check them. But as you've discovered, checking for errors at every step also makes your code more verbose and less clear. If you control the API you're using, modify it to indicate errors by throwing exceptions.

Comment: Take a look at railway oriented programming

Comment: I like questions like this. But they’re not well-suited for Stack Overflow, since they’re fundamentally opinion based. This might be well-suited for [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

With railway oriented programming your code could look like this

```cs
            var result =
                CreateCustomerRequest(requestDataInput)
                .Bind(c => GetCustomerInfo(new FetchCustomerDataInput()))
                .Bind(i => SaveCustomerDetails(i.Customer))
                .Bind(d => CreateCustomerItemMappingRequest(d.IdList))
                .Bind(m => UpdateCustomerRequest(RequestId))
                .Join(updated => true, error => false);
```

It depends on `Result<TValue, TError>` which may contain either value or error, but not both. `Bind` takes function which accepts value and return another `Result<TValue, TError>`. `Result` is not something builtin, so you need to implement it on your own or look for existing implementation.
Scott Wlaschin have [blog](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/) and [talk](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/) about it

Comment: The error I am getting, Model doesn't contain a definition of Bind.

Comment: @JOJO Your function should return not just `Model` but `Result<Error, Model>`. See my implementation of Result [here](https://pastebin.com/Wspk7xJP).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to inverse if. It is easier to read and understand:

```
    var result =  CreateCustomerRequest(requestDataInput);
      if (result.Error.HasError) return ... error;
    var result1 = GetCustomerInfo(new FetchCustomerDataInput());
      if (result1.Error.HasError) return ... error;
    var result2 = SaveCustomerDetails(result1.cutomer);
      if (result2.Error.HasError) return ...error;
    var result3 =  CreateCustomerItemMappingRequest(result2.IdList);
      if (result3.Error.HasError) return ...error;
    var result4 = UpdateCustomerRequestStatus(RequestId);
```